# How to disallow disposable email in firebase auth email provider signup?

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

We are using firebase auth and firebase auth UI to authenticate a user.

We want to disallow or block those user's, who is trying to use a temporary mailbox for signing up (eg: https://www.mailinator.com).

There are 2 proposed solutions:

1. Do a client-side validation for the email ID? (Difficult to manage a blacklist of email providers in the client. Also, people can still use API to hack it).
2. After the user signs up, on onCreate user event, we can trigger a firebase function to validate the email ID against the blacklist, then we can disable or revoke the account. But here,

   - if we are disabling the user, he/she will get access to our app for next 1 hour as the client already gained the ID token.
   - If we are revoking refresh token, we'll have to again wait for 1 hour or write the rule to make a query to Firestore to check if user access is revoked. (Better if we can avoid this query)

Is there a better or native way to solve this issue?

If we are not getting any other solutions, we'll choose to go with 2nd option (revoking refresh token).

Answer (score 2):

I would do a combination of both solutions you proposed. Doing the client side check will trip up most people and for the more tech savvy that try to get around it, your onCreate trigger will deal with them.

You could also add their uid to a blocked list in the realtime database from your onCreate trigger.

Then you can listen to it on the client and log them out. And for database rules you can check if they are in the block list and so block the read/write rule.

Answer (score 0):

a regularly updated service to check DPA is already being maintained.

Do a simple get request to: 
https://open.kickbox.com/v1/disposable/{user_email}

this would return the response 
{
    "disposable": true
}
if email id is disposable.

you can send the get request with complete email id or just the domain.

e.g. https://open.kickbox.com/v1/disposable/**jamond67@zdecaesgl.com**
or https://open.kickbox.com/v1/disposable/**zdecaesgl.com**